# C# random function algorithm implementation and its randomness

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

What is the c# [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) algorithm implementation and is it a good pseudo-random from cryptography perspective?

Comment: *Which* C# random implementation? Please be specific, and provide a link!

Comment: MSDN says: "The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.". But some people claim that the implementation has a bug and that this bug reduces the quality of the random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source to `Random` can be see here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs

The `Random` class is not cryptographically secure.  For security purposes, use the `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class.

**Edit 18/04/2021**: For .NET Core, you should use the `RandomNumberGenerator` class for a cross-platform random number generator suitable for security-related scenarios.